# How to do SQL Server "TEXTIMAGE_ON" in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity, blob

In SQL Server there is an option how to store in a table some columns in separate pages.

Can such an option be enabled in entity via Entity Framework?

Thanks